# Make SpEL Indexer return `null` if `target == null`

Tags: spring-expression

I want to be able to convert expression into `null` if I have something like `<expression evaluating to null>['field'].and.so.on` without changing expression. This behaviour should be driven by `EvaluationContext`.

Now, I only get exception thrown [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/main/spring-expression/src/main/java/org/springframework/expression/spel/ast/Indexer.java#L150).